How to filter an array of objects by key
There are similar questions to this but I cannot find something to tackle this one exactly.
I have an Array that is shaped like this:
AllReviews: [

{"0001": [
         {"Review": "In a Pickle", "Notes": "Approved"},
         {"Review": "A Cat Nap", "Notes": "Approved"},
         {"Review": "Flea market", "Notes": "Approved"}
       ]
},
{"0002": [
         {"Review": "Mouth-watering", "Notes": "Approved"},
         {"Review": "Easy As Pie", "Notes": "Approved"},
       ]
},
{"0003": [
         {"Review": "Loved it", "Notes": "Approved"},
         {"Review": "To sweet", "Notes": "Rejected"}
       ]
}

]

I want to filter this Array so that it only returns the review for 002. I cannot figure out how to do it. My attempt was feeble:
AllReviews.value.filter((Review) => {
   for (const [Key, Value] of Object.entries(Review)) {
    return Review[Key] === 0002 // Trying to say return the value (the array with reviews and notes) where the Key of the object matches what I want e.g. 0002
 }
})

My code is a nonsense of course and will not work.

Why Review[Key] in Review[Key] == 002? You want to filter by key, not by review.

@jabaa I dont know what Im doing. I just want the value for 0002 but cant figure out the code to select it

@MisterJojo yes you're right, I typed it manually into the SO editor and forgot all the quotations

The better solution would be to fix your json so that it's Property:Value, rather than the current Value:Value.  eg AllReviews = [ { "ID":"0001", "Reviews": [ {...

@fdomn-m but it isn't Value:Value. It is Property(0002):Value(Object): isn't it?

Perhaps this wording:  change to "Key":"Value" or "PropertyName":"Value" - in the JSON.   Value(0002) isn't a key / property name and it's not JSON.

@fdomn-m Although the two solutions below work, after progressing further, you were correct that having the data as [{ "ReviewID": "12345", "Reviews": [ {... makes working with it so much easier. It was very hard to do inserts and deletes with the original structure.

Simply:


const AllReviews =
    [ { '0001': 
        [ { Review: 'In a Pickle', Notes: 'Approved'} 
        , { Review: 'A Cat Nap',   Notes: 'Approved'} 
        , { Review: 'Flea market', Notes: 'Approved'} 
      ] } 
    , { '0002': 
        [ { Review: 'Mouth-watering', Notes: 'Approved'} 
        , { Review: 'Easy As Pie',   Notes: 'Approved'} 
      ] } 
    , { '0003': 
        [ { Review: 'Loved it', Notes: 'Approved'} 
        , { Review: 'To sweet', Notes: 'Rejected'} 
    ] } ];
    
const Result = AllReviews.filter( row => row.hasOwnProperty('0002') );

console.log( Result );
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100% !important;top:0}
.as-console-row::after{display:none !important;}




Thanks for this, I was working on it myself for even longer and I think it came up with a solution. What do you think?

@volumeone I think that always, at least in terms of coding, the best solution is the one that is the simplest to understand...

I agree but sometimes we don't have control over the source data

Why not just use find? We don't need to loop through whole array if we already found one (of course if the parameter unique)

@EzioMercer, Right, a .find() or a .findIndex() would be better in case there is only one row with this property. But the OP's question asks to use a filter, without clearly specifying if there are other rows meeting this criterion.

I figured it out myself:


let AllReviews = [
{"0001": [
         {"Review": "In a Pickle", "Notes": "Approved"},
         {"Review": "A Cat Nap", "Notes": "Approved"},
         {"Review": "Flea market", "Notes": "Approved"}
       ]
},
{"0002": [
         {"Review": "Mouth-watering", "Notes": "Approved"},
         {"Review": "Easy As Pie", "Notes": "Approved"},
       ]
},
{"0003": [
         {"Review": "Loved it", "Notes": "Approved"},
         {"Review": "To sweet", "Notes": "Rejected"}
       ]
}
];

let Result;
AllReviews.forEach((Review) => {
  for (const [Key, Value] of Object.entries(Review)) {
    if (Number(Key) === 0002 && Value != null && Value.length) {
      Result = {
        [Key]: Review[Key]
      }
    }
  }
})

console.log(Result);



Obviously 0002 will not be hardcoded in production and is a variable.

The test is whether it gives you the correct result.  I've converted to a snippet for you, but perhaps I've not provided the correct definition for AllReviews = - please edit the snippet to demonstrate it working.  (.map rather than .forEach to provide a return value, but then also need to filter nulls)

@fdomn-m Done the edit to show working

@volume one; may be just use if (Number(Key) === 2 && .... or if (Key === '0002' &&.....

@Haluk They are IDs from a database of type Integer. So 002 will be entered as a Number. I suppose I could convert the 0002.toString() instead.
